# Resisted motion involving densities?

Tags: calculus, classical-mechanics

A space craft in the shape of a cylinder has mass $N$ and the area of its cross section is $B$. It is moving at constant velocity but meets a dust cloud, with the dust sticking to the spaceship. If the dust has density $d$, how far does the vehicle travel before it has half the velocity of the original?

Comment: Presumably this is a conservation of momentum exercise, given the information about the cross section (area?) and "dust sticking to the spaceship".  But the title suggests you were trying to approach this in terms of frictional dissipation of kinetic energy.  In the future please include more of the details of your thoughts about solving in the body of the Question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Drag force $F=\frac12dv^2CB$, where $C$ is drag constant and $v$ is the velocity.

Let the initial velocity $v_0$.

\begin{align}
&F=-N\frac{dv}{dt}=\frac12dv^2CB\\
&\frac{v'}{v^2}=-\frac{dCB}{2N}\\
&v(t)=\frac{1}{C+\frac{dCB}{2N}t}\\
&v(0)=\frac1C=v_0\\
&\therefore v(t)=\frac{1}{\frac1{v_0}+\frac{dCB}{2N}t}\\
\end{align}
Let the time of half velocity $t_1$.
\begin{align}
&v(t_1)=\frac{v_0}2=\frac{1}{\frac1{v_0}+\frac{dCB}{2N}t_1}\\
&t_1=\frac{2N}{dCBv_0}\\
\end{align}
Total distance until $t_1$ is
\begin{align}
&\int_0^{t_1}v(t)dt=\int_0^{t_1}\frac{1}{\frac1{v_0}+\frac{dCB}{2N}t}dt=\left.\frac{2N}{dCB}\ln\left(\frac1{v_0}+\frac{dCB}{2N}t\right)\right]_0^{\frac{2N}{dCBv_0}}\\
&=\frac{2N}{dCB}\left(\ln \frac2{v_0}-\ln \frac1{v_0}\right)=\frac{2N}{dCB}\ln2
\end{align}